# C# chart axis labels position change

Tags: c#, charts, label

I want to change those values on left side of screen (149 169 189 209 229) positon on chart from left to right side of form, how can i do this? I think its somewhere in `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY`, but i cant find it.
i cant post image so here is the link of my form and values: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1484/clipboardcc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `Y Axis` to `Secondary`

Example:

```
  myLines.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```